# How do I report a Texmaker bug?

Tags: texmaker

The only issue tracker I could find is archived as Google Code: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/bugtrackers/texmaker-bugs links to  https://code.google.com/archive/p/texmaker/

Searching for other Texmaker bugs, I saw some distros appeared to maintain their own patches.

Comment: I would send a message to the author and ask: https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html#contact

Comment: Any luck contacting the developer? v5.1.2 syntax highlighting has plenty of bugs.

Comment: Nope, not yet. In the meantime I switched to TexStudio